# How to programatically create a tile in Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, live-tile

In Windows Phone 8 I was able to create a Shell Tile with the following:

```
StandardTileData newTileData = new StandardTileData
{
    BackgroundImage = new Uri("/Images/my_tile_medium.png", UriKind.Relative),
    Title = "My Tile Title",
    BackTitle = "My Tile Back",
    BackBackgroundImage = new Uri("/Images/my_tile_medium_back.png", UriKind.Relative),
};

ShellTile.Create(MyAppPages.MainPage("Name=MyAppTile"), newTileData);
```

This no longer works in Windows Phone 8.1. How can I programatically create a tile with Windows Phone 8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WP8.1 Runtime you can use [SecondaryTile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.startscreen.secondarytile.aspx), for example:

```cs
SecondaryTile tileData = new SecondaryTile()
{
    TileId = "MyTileID",
    DisplayName = "MyTilesTitle",
    Arguments = "Some arguments"
};
tileData.VisualElements.Square150x150Logo = new Uri("uri to image");
tileData.VisualElements.ShowNameOnSquare150x150Logo = true;
await tileData.RequestCreateAsync();
```

Some guide you can also find [here at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465372.aspx).