# How to add / remove default tile / secondary tile for Windows phone 8.1 (universal) applications from code?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

n windows phone 8 silverlight application we can add / remove tiles from the code as below

```
ShellTile.Create(tileUri, tileData, true);
```

and we can get the tiles based on the Uri like below

```
ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NavigationUri.ToString().Contains("/"));
```

How we can do similarly in windows phone 8.1 (universal) applications?

I could not get clear information or samples.

Answer (score 6):

When you want to create a tile, you can do it as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24997576/2681948):

```cs
SecondaryTile tileData = new SecondaryTile()
{
    TileId = "MyTileID",
    DisplayName = "MyTilesTitle",
    Arguments = "Some arguments"
};
tileData.VisualElements.Square150x150Logo = new Uri("uri to image");
await tileData.RequestCreateAsync();
```

When you want to delete a tile, then you will have to find your tile (for example by its ID), then call `RequestDeleteAsync()`:

```
SecondaryTile tile = (await SecondaryTile.FindAllAsync()).FirstOrDefault((t) => t.TileId == "your tile's ID");
if (tile != null) await tile.RequestDeleteAsync();
```

Some [more information at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465372.aspx).