# Windows Phone 8.1 RT pin page to start

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I have 10 Pages which I want to pin pages to start.
I've been used the ["Secondary tiles sample"](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/secondary-tiles-sample-edf2a178) from Microsoft.

It works fine, but I want when User pinned from Page2, when in Start tap on Page2, my application shows Page2.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this [Link](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/how-to-add-and-remove-secondary-tiles-in-windows-phone-apps) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks but this is for Windows Phone 8.0 and Windows Phone 8.1 sliverlight version. dosen't work on Windows Phone 8.1 runtime. Please give me for windows phone 8.1 rt version

Comment: What about this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25564549/how-to-add-remove-default-tile-secondary-tile-for-windows-phone-8-1-univers

Comment: I saw this before. it only pinned the program not page