# Windows Phone 8.1 How to programatically create a tile with specified template

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, live-tile

I'm trying to figure out how to create programatically a tile with specified template (TileSquare150x150Text03)? I tried to follow these guides [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thunbrynt/archive/2014/04/10/windows-phone-8-1-for-developers-live-tiles.aspx) , [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868253.aspx)
and a few similiar, but wherever I paste < tile> ... < /tile > markup (e.g. in page or app .xaml file) Visual Studio underlines this markup and says that "tile is not supported in a Windows Phone project". I don't need any tile updates or tiles with two sides. Just simple one with specified template, background color/image and filled with my text.

Can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you targeting *Silverlight* or *RunTime*? How have you tried to create the tile? You may take a look [at this answer (WinRT)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24997576/2681948).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'm targeting RunTime. This code works fine with me, but how can I set SecondaryTile one of built-in templates? With this solution I have only one line of text at the bottom of the tile, but I need to display at least 3 or 4 lines like in TileSquare150x150Text03 template.

Comment: I think you will need to send a notification to a tile, which uses templates you are talking about. [Good reference is at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh868253(v=win.10).aspx).

Comment: I mentioned about this site in my first post. The problem is mainly with < tile> ... < /tile > tag. I can't add this markup to any .xaml file in my project without getting an error. I'm working on VSE 2013.

Comment: There are couple of ways you can obtain XmlDocument: 1. The easiest will be just to get a template: `TileUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(TileTemplateType.TileWide310x150ImageAndText01);`. 2. Load from string `var doc = new XmlDocument(); doc.LoadXml(string);` You put your `<tile>..` in `string str = @"<tile>...`. 3. You can also load document from file `XmlDocument.LoadFromFileAsync()` - for this add xml file in your project.

Answer (score -1):

Simple! You need to parse your tile template (an XML string) into an XElement object *in code*:

```
var template = "<tile>etc</tile>";
var tileXe = XElement.Parse(template);
```

Either configure the template xml to your liking before this or after (demo is in the article you linked)

then post it to the tile manager

```
var tileNotification = new TileNotification(tileXe);
TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Update(tileNotification);
```

You can do this anywhere in your app as long as this code runs on the UI thread. Also note that there is a limit to how often you can update the tile, last time I checked it was every 15 seconds at most.